# Bubble Sort Bash Script

Tags: bash, scripts

This is the error I'm getting when running:

```
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: 4: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
./sortNums.sh: line 10: [: -gt: unary operator expected
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

bubbleSort()
{
for ((i=0;i<=${#nums[@]};i++))
do
    for ((j=0;j<=${#nums[@]};j++))
    do
        if [ ${nums[$i]} -gt ${nums[$j]} ]
        then
            t=${nums[$i]}
            nums[$i]=${nums[$j]}
            nums[$j]=$t
        fi
    done
done
}

declare -a nums=(89 62 11 75 8 33 95 4)
echo ${nums[*]} #prints out all elems
bubbleSort
echo ${nums[*]} #prints out all elems
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing `i <= ${#nums[@]}`. Arrays in bash are 0-indexed, as you already know, so the last element is at `${#nums[@]} - 1`. When `i` is `${#nums[@]}` and you do `nums[$i]=${nums[$j]}` or `nums[$j]=$t`, you add after the end of the array, increasing the size of the array and thus creating an infinite loop.

The errors you see are also due to this, but because the assignment hasn't been done yet, `${array[non-existent index]}` is just empty. Consider the output under `bash -x`:

```
+ (( j++ ))                                     # j is 8
+ (( j<=8 ))                                    # perfectly fine
+ '[' 4 -gt ']'                                 # but nums[j] is empty
./foo.sh: line 9: [: 4: unary operator expected
+ (( j++ ))
+ (( j<=8 ))
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<=8 ))
+ (( j=0 ))
+ (( j<=8 ))
+ '[' 89 -gt 4 ']'
+ t=89
+ nums[$i]=4
+ nums[$j]=89
+ (( j++ ))
+ (( j<=8 ))
+ '[' 4 -gt 4 ']'
+ (( j++ ))
+ (( j<=8 ))
+ '[' 4 -gt 62 ']'
+ (( j++ ))
+ (( j<=8 ))
+ '[' 4 -gt 75 ']'
+ (( j++ ))
+ (( j<=8 ))
```

This continues until the expression is `[ -gt ]`. With a single argument, the test is just for a non-empty argument, so this succeeds, assignments take place and infinite loops begin.

Do:

- **Always quote your variables.**

Don't:

- Test for equality for end-of-array tests in languages with 0-indexed arrays.